# R - how to use/pass a string as a column name with factor()

Tags: r

Let' s say that :

```
colstr="mycol"
```

Now, for a given df that contains a column named mycol, I want to do the following :

```
myfactors <- factor(df$colstr)
```

This does not work as the command is executed as:

```
myfactors <- factor(df$"mycol")
```

istead of the correct :

```
myfactors <- factor(df$mycol)
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/dynamically-select-data-frame-columns-using-and-a-character-value) might help?

Comment: `factor(df[colstr])`.

Comment: You can't use the `$` notation that way. The variable after the `$` is always read as-is, and not substitued. To get the correct column if the name is stored as a character is `df[colstr]`, which will be the same as `df$mycol`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `df` is a `data.frame` and you are good to go. I used the following example and it worked for me:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, mycol=letters[1:10])
myfactors <- factor(df$mycol)
myfactors
```

Here's the output:

```
 [1] a b c d e f g h i j
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
```

In a data frame, there is no need to use quotation or double-quotation to call a column (variable).

Comment: I think you have missed the point of the question, which is how to access a column name when that name is stored as a character variable.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks for the heads up. I didn't notice that part.